# How do the Hindu scriptures explain spiritual communication through a medium?

Tags: rebirth, afterlife

My understanding of karmic responsibility keeps me from understanding how a soul can be free to communicate through mediumship. Can someone please direct me to resources that explain the afterlife from a Vedic perspective?

Comment: There are methods to change and wash away past Karmas... Just do that process you will know your own Atma if you do that!

Comment: @AkshayS thank you for your reply. I'm not asking how to wash away karma. I'm asking are Hindus skeptical of people who call themselves 'mediums' and 'channel' people from the afterlife? How can a soul be

Comment: (cont.)...be available to communicate through a 'medium' if they are reborn into a new life (new person...)? How is the remanence of that personality available to communicate after death?

Comment: Meduims for whom? Atma doesnt get another body in Earth quickly after it left previous body.

Comment: this is a topic on planchet which i think theosophists can answer